# JasperSoft - Date Format Pattern

Tags: rest, jasper-reports, jasperserver

My version of jasperSoft is:

```
<serverInfo><build>BUILD_DATE_STAMP_BUILD_TIME_STAMP</build><dateFormatPattern>yyyy-MM-dd</dateFormatPattern> <datetimeFormatPattern>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:s:s:s:ss</datetimeFormatPattern> <edition>CE</edition><version>6.1</version> </serverInfo>
```

---

> **The situation:** when I generate the report in local host like
>   localhost:8080/jasperserver/, I realize that input field type date
>   like "20/05/2018" converted to "2018-05-20" before send for JASPER
>   server.

I have ERP that call jasper through REST and, in my application, my data format are always 'dd/mm/yyyy', I can't change that because I haven't access to source code.

My question are: I'll have do anyway to change jasper server for accept the format date input like  format 'dd/mm/yyyy'?

> Attachment image for better understanding: https://i.stack.imgur.com/df2pt.jpg

Comment: Please have a look at [changing date format/pattern in input control](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/531608/changing-date-formatpattern-input-control)

Comment: Did not work ... Attached is attached for a better understanding of the problem: https://imgur.com/a/3Ev6X1a